# update Community String in SNMP exporter deployed using Helm Charts

Tags: authentication, kubernetes, monitoring, snmp, network-monitoring

I have deployed SNMP exporter using Prometheus helm chart. How could I update SNMP community string? should I change in values.yaml file or some other file?

I did try to add auth section in few places in values.yaml file but it didn´t work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.